# Do Windows Shell APIs work with long Unicode paths?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I can't seem to find the answer to this in MSDN. I'm curious, if I have something like this:

```
LPITEMIDLIST pidl = NULL;
HRESULT hr = SHParseDisplayName(L"\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Name\\Folder", NULL, &pidl, 0, NULL);
```

It fails with `HRESULT` set to `E_INVALIDARG`. The issue goes away if I supply the path as `"C:\\Users\\Name\\Folder"`, which is limited only to `MAX_PATH` characters.

Are those Shell APIs not compatible with long Unicode paths?

Comment: An interesting related discusssion here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx I'm not sure Vista works any better about this, it's still very unclear: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically no, it is not supported.  `\\?\` is a feature of the lower level file I/O API, not the higher level Shell API.  `\\?\` does not represent a Shell namespace.

**Update**: For something like parsing a long file path into a PIDL, you may need to manually divide the path string into its individual pieces and use `IShellFolder` directly to parse each one into parent/child PIDLs recursively as needed.  If nothing else, that will help you identify which subfolder breaks the parsing, then you can report that to the user: "sorry, Windows path length limitation reached, cannot work with files/folder underneath path XXX".

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. How do you deal with paths longer than 260 chars then?

Answer (score 2):

No, the Shell API functions are (in general) not compatible with long Unicode paths.

E.g. in the documentation of the inverse function of `SHParseDisplayName`, namely `SHGetPathFromIDList`, you find

> *pszPath* [out]
>   Type: **`LPTSTR`**
>   The address of a buffer to receive the file system path. This buffer must be at least `MAX_PATH` characters in size.

And in general the documentation notes this path length restriction for each relevant function, but AFAICS it's not there as a higher level overall general statement.

---

From a development point of view it's only reasonable to create >`MAX_PATH` paths, or e.g. paths involving reserved names such as `CON`, if they will not be handled by an ordinary end-user, because Windows Explorer refuses to handle them.

(I checked just now. Windows 8.1 Explorer refuses silently to delete a folder named `con`. I think it should, because an ordinary end user will find it difficult to remove it.)

A power user can work around the shell's path length limitation, in order to e.g. delete or rename, by leveraging some bugs in the command interpreter, by using `subst` drives, by using DOS shortnames, by writing programs that call the API functions, and possibly other techniques (hopefully not by disk editing). But to the average end user such techniques are unknown. So when the average end user gets some undesired >`MAX_PATH` path, then that user is stuck with it.

Comment: Oh, no. It's actually the opposite. We've got a tech support request from one of those "average end-users" with a 
"favorite" line for any developer -- "your program doesn't work." So it took me several days to drill down to the cause -- the end-user has a gianormous folder with very long folder names, which makes paths exceed 259 chars. That is why I'm asking. It is not just `SHParseDisplayName`, the API that we've got bit by the most is `PathFileExists` which should be banned from existence!

Comment: Possibly it may be better in the long run to provide reasonable feedback about "exceeding Windows' path length" (put the blame where it should be) than trying to work around, because if user get workaround then next the user might complain about folders and files that Explorer can't handle...

Comment: Yes, that's one way to handle it. As for your other comment. You know I just did a test on my Windows 8.1 pro. I created a folder longer than 259 chars (using \\?\ prefix) and then created a text file in it. I then deleted it and tried to restore it from the Recycle Bin and crashed the Windows Explorer... Haha. I can't believe we're still dealing with this in Windows 8.1.